# How can I access the changed variable on rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

How can I access a changed values before and after update?

Suppose, I have Person1.

`Person1.friends = [P2, P3, P4]`

and then I update it so it becomes:

```
Person1.friends = [P2, P3]
```

how can I access the previous `Person1.friends`, so I could know that only `P4` is removed from `Person1.friends`

I tried to compare `Person1.friends` on `before_update` and `after_update`, but they both yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that Person1.friends is the value taken from the form in your update controller, and has therefore had the attributes changed, although not saved to the database. What you could therefore do is the following.

In the controller carry out the following before the save / update command

```
personold = Person.where( query for the person based on a value that haasn't changed).first
```

or you do a similar thing in the edit action

```
@personold = Person1
```

or somethig on those lines

Answer (score 0):

Person.friends simply returns a collection based on it's relation like so:

```
where(person_id: person.id)
```

Instead of trying to recover the removed person from the collection try setting up the CRUD logic so that the destroy method in your controller returns the one removed like so:

```
select_person = Person.friends.find(1)
select_person.destroy
=> #<User id: 1, email: 'test@test.com'>
```